# UITableCell's expanding incorrectly after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have a UITableView with different types of cells and in particular I have one that displays connections. It includes two labels and a button and two image views. I believe all the constraints are correct because it does load correctly initially, but as you scroll the cells become a larger height. Does anyone have any ideas?

Original Load:
[image: original]

After Scroll:
[image: after scroll]

Comment: After scrolling, cells start getting reused. Share your `HeightForCell` delegate method here

Comment: What @NSNoob said, it's likely you have a cell caching issue. Make sure your recalculating/configuring your heights properly for each dequeued cell.

Comment: I had a feeling it might have to do with the dequeuing process. I'm using Swift so I just have this `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 83.0

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`